# Inserting Variables From Jquery Always Fails

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i have some problem, i made some local website using php.

I have a file called functions.php which this is the code:

```
public function saveAll($idmt_salesarea, $thn_bln, $no_pesanan, $tgl_pesan, $idms_langganan, $idms_kodebarang, $quantity, $harga, $jumlah, $disc_cash, $disc_kredit){
    $message = "Waiting input...";
    try{
        $con = new db();
        $conn = $con->connect();
        $query = "INSERT INTO mt_pesanan(idmt_salesarea,thn_bln,no_pesanan,tgl_pesan,idms_langganan, idms_kodebarang,quantity,harga,jumlah,disc_cash,disc_kredit) VALUES ($idmt_salesarea, '$thn_bln', '$no_pesanan', '$tgl_pesan', $idms_langganan, $idms_kodebarang, '$quantity', $harga, $jumlah, '$disc_cash', '$disc_kredit')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn) . "  " . mysqli_errno());
        if($result == 1){
            $message = "Success";
        } else if($result == 0){
            $message = "Failed";
        }
    }catch(Exception $exc){
        echo $exc->getCode();
    }
        $con->disconnect();
        return $message;
}
```

i Take the input parameter from file called: index.php and pass the parameter using AJAX Jquery. The parameter itself is sent and pointing to file called insert.php

here's the insert.php file:

```
 <?php

  include_once 'functions.php';

    $idmt_salesarea = isset($_GET['salesarea']);
    $thn_bln = isset($_GET['thn_bln']);
    $no_pesanan = isset($_GET['nopes']);
    $tgl_pesan = isset($_GET['tglpes']);
    $idms_langganan = isset($_GET['idlangganan']);
    $idms_kodebarang = isset($_GET['idbarang']);
    $quantity = isset($_GET['quantity']);
    $harga = isset($_GET['harga']);
    $jumlah = isset($_GET['jumlah']);

    $disc_cash = isset($_GET['disc_cash']);
    $disc_kredit = isset($_GET['disc_kredit']);
    if (($disc_cash == null) || ($disc_kredit == null)) {
        $disc_cash = 0;
        $disc_kredit = 0;
    }

    $insert = new functions();
    $insert->saveAll($idmt_salesarea, $thn_bln, $no_pesanan, $tgl_pesan, $idms_langganan, $idms_kodebarang, $quantity, $harga, $jumlah, $disc_cash, $disc_kredit);

 ?>
```

but when i check the error, that is the variable that cannot get from insert.php file (using **$_GET statement**).

How proper way to gain the variable? because all the parameter is set.

I know this is combining object oriented style and old fashion php coding. Any ideas?

thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

here's the index.php file using jquery ajax to sent the data

```
    function sendAll(){
            var tgl_pesan = $('#dpc').val();
            var sales_area = $('#sales_area').val();
            var nopes = $('#no_pesanan').val();
            var thnbln = getTahunBulan();
            var id_langganan = $('#kode_langganan').val();
            var id_barang = $('#kode_barang').val();
            var quantity = getQuantity();
            var harga = $('#harga').val();
            var jumlah = $('#jumlah').val();
            var disc_cash = $('#cash').val();
            var disc_kredit = $('#kredit').val();
            var max = $('#max').val();

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                **url:"insert.php",**
                data:{
                  salesarea:sales_area,
                  thn_bln:thnbln,
                  nopes:nopes,
                  tglpes:tgl_pesan,
                  idlangganan:id_langganan,
                  idbarang:id_barang,
                  quantity:quantity,
                  harga:harga,
                  jumlah:jumlah,
                  disc_cash:disc_cash,
                  disc_kredit:disc_kredit,
                  max:max
                },
                success:function(msg){
                   alert("Data Inserted"); 
                },
                error:function(msg){
                   alert("Data Failed to save" + msg); 
                }
            });
```

the ajax itself is pointing to file insert.php which the insert.php is executing function from another file called functions.php

Comment: What is the error?  What do you want to achieve that you are not able to achieve right now?

Comment: @Coulton the error is the insert.php file cannot get the variable sent from ajax jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this code:

```
$idmt_salesarea = isset($_GET['salesarea']);
$thn_bln = isset($_GET['thn_bln']);
$no_pesanan = isset($_GET['nopes']);
$tgl_pesan = isset($_GET['tglpes']);
$idms_langganan = isset($_GET['idlangganan']);
$idms_kodebarang = isset($_GET['idbarang']);
$quantity = isset($_GET['quantity']);
$harga = isset($_GET['harga']);
$jumlah = isset($_GET['jumlah']);

$disc_cash = isset($_GET['disc_cash']);
$disc_kredit = isset($_GET['disc_kredit']);
```

For each of those variables, you are assigning the result of `isset()`, which will evaluate to either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If you want to bind the actual value of your `$_GET` input, change each line from this syntax:

```
$idmt_salesarea = isset($_GET['salesarea']);
```

To

```
$idmt_salesarea = isset($_GET['salesarea']) ? $_GET['salesarea'] : '';
```

However this code isn't really maintainable, and I would also recommend using arrays instead of passing that many arguments to your `saveAll()` method.

**In response to your update**

If you are sending an AJAX request with `type: "POST"`, you cannot access your input data via the PHP `$_GET` super global, you have to use `$_POST`. However, what I said before is still valid, as you aren't binding values to your variables properly.

Comment: hi @rainFromHeaven, the question is updated to give clear understanding. So i have a file: index.php which is using the ajax above to send the data. The pointing file is insert.php that executing a function from file called functions.php but the $_GET method cannot get the variable sent from ajax. any help?

Comment: If you're sending an AJAX request with `type: "POST"`, then you have to use `$_POST` in your PHP. But you have to take my answer into consideration, because you are not properly assigning values to your variables.

Comment: oh my God, i forgot to change that. that is stupid mistake. thanks a lot friend.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not get what you are saying completely, still based on your description the problem can be you sending the variable using ajax call. If the ajax call is async you might not get the value by the time you use it.

So you can either set async:false in the ajax call (which is not a good way) or trigger any thing that uses that variable from within the success callback handler of the ajax call.

It would be really helpful if you can share the piece of code which explains the following statement of yours.... "i Take the input parameter from file called: index.php and pass the parameter using AJAX Jquery. The parameter itself is sent and pointing to file called insert.php"

Comment: the question is updated. Please see the question again. thank you.